# django1.8 filter list_filter based on login

Tags: python, django

In django 1.8 how to you filter the list_filter based on logged in user? I cannot use SimpleListFilter from django.contrib.admin as I use django.contrib.admin.apps.SimpleAdminConfig to register a view using AdminPlus.

Some code that I tried in the ModelAdmin:

```
def get_list_filter(self, request):
    my_list_filter = super(SubCategoryAdmin, self).get_list_filter(request)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        pass
    else:
        my_list_filter = self.get_queryset(request)

    return my_list_filter

def get_queryset(self, request):
    '''
    Superuser has all permissions.
    '''
    qs = super(SubCategoryAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        pass
    else:
        qs = qs.filter(
            category__in=Category.objects.filter(
                department__in=Department.objects.filter(
                    name=request.user.customuser.department.name)))
    return qs
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Followed the docs and found the answer here: `[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/][1]`

**Sharing my answer:**

```
class UserCategoryListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    # Human-readable title which will be displayed in the
    # right admin sidebar just above the filter options.
    title = _('Department',)

    # Parameter for the filter that will be used in the URL query.
    parameter_name = 'department'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        """
        Returns a list of tuples. The first element in each
        tuple is the coded value for the option that will
        appear in the URL query. The second element is the
        human-readable name for the option that will appear
        in the right sidebar.
        """
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            return (
                (request.user.customuser.department.name, _(request.user.customuser.department.name)),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        """
        Returns the filtered queryset based on the value
        provided in the query string and retrievable via
        `self.value()`.
        """
        # to decide how to filter the queryset.
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            if self.value() == request.user.customuser.department.name:
                return queryset.filter(
                    department__in=Department.objects.filter(
                        name=request.user.customuser.department.name))
        else:
            return queryset
```

In the modeladmin:

```
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}        

        if request.user.is_superuser:
            self.list_filter = ['department','name']
        else:
            self.list_filter = (UserCategoryListFilter,)
```

Comment: For posterity, could you include the relevant parts of the link which you found useful in your answer? That way, if the link goes down, changes, etc., your answer won't be rendered useless. Many thanks.